# How to bind form data using spring @ModelAttribute in a model which contains reference of different object

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Hi I have a form which have many input tags with address input tag like below

```
input tag for : name
input tag for :password
input tage for : stree
input tage for : city
input tage for : state
```

The problem is with model where i have Address class inside user class like below

```
private String name;
private String password;
private Address address;
```

How to pass values of address inside Address class using spring @ModelAttribute annotation

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of the class you provided is "Person" ( Person has an Address).
hence 2 classes Person class and an Address Class. Make sure the getters and setters are
set for the variables and object references.

```
<form:form method="post" action="" modelAttribute="Person">

<form:input type="text" placeholder="" path="name" />
<form:input type="password" placeholder="" path="password" />
<form:input type="text" placeholder="" path="address.street" />
<form:input type="text" placeholder="" path="address.city" />
<form:input type="text" placeholder="" path="address.state" />

</form:form>
```

Comment: What about name attribute in input tags? Path attribute is behaving like name attribute ?

Comment: No it behaves differently.. path attribute will directly bind your input fields with modelattribute you are referencing it with. if you use name attribute you will have to explicitly map the input field within the controller using @RequestParam annotation... kindly mark my answer correct if it was useful, thanks

Comment: When i am using it i am getting following error in infinite loop.
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander.expand(ModelAttributeParameterExpander.java:110) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]

Comment: Same above one in infinite loop not able to see full stack trace.

Comment: This article discusses the issue. https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/621. Basically update your Spring dependencies to version 4

Comment: Thank you for reference but I suspect this will fix the problem because I am not refering person in address just using @Embeded annotation in person class to embed address class inside it, I am using 2.1 spring boot and spring boot jpa, dependency is being managed by spring starter so I guess I am using latest one.

Comment: Yes with the limited code you've provided it is impossible to come to a conclusion. but yes you need to add private Person person in your address class to properly structure the mapping. again the jpa level code needs to be observed

Comment: Can you please look into link you get an idea , if you want I can edit my question and paste codes here.